# Invoke a function by statement in click event

Tags: javascript, angular, callback, dom-events

### How can we invoke a function with parameter if a statement is return true?

Something Like this below way

```
(click)="datavalue.elementDataCollection.length > 1 ? AddNewDialog
(datavalue,datavalue.COCLabel,mainindex,i) : return false"
```

---

**I don't want this below ways:**

- I won't check this statement in `AddNewDialog()`. I need call the function directly in `click` event if the statement is true.
- I don't want create duplicate DOM elements

---

> And also I got a answer from this discussion: [Call function on condition in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40415629/call-function-on-condition-in-angular-2/40415697#40415697). 
>   but I don't know how to handle this way with function parameters.

Comment: Did you try removing `return` from `: return false`?

Comment: How about `datavalue.elementDataCollection.length > 1 && AddNewDialog
(datavalue,datavalue.COCLabel,mainindex,i)`

Comment: @Vinay I have tried yours, but the function does not fire. and it does not shows any error on console :( :(

Comment: Is it because the length is less than or equal to 1?

Comment: `elementDataCollection.length` is 132  :(

Comment: let me know is this way is possible in angular 2?

Comment: Why don't check  `elementDataCollection.length > 1` in body of `AddNewDialog()` function?I mean is that check it in body of function and if it is not ok return false and other.

Comment: Yes the way I suggested works fine in angular 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can normally try this where `AlertUser` is custom function

```
<button (click)="data.length && AlertUser('user')">Click Me</button>
```